# git readme.md does not reflect maven coordinates

Tags: markdown

We have a git repository at work.
I need to provide maven coordinates of the artefact in the README.md file.

The maven coordinates are:

```
\<dependency\>
   \<groupId\>com.company.dept.project.team\</groupId\>
   \<artifactId\>LibraryName\</artifactId\>
   \<version\>1.0\</version\>
\</dependency\>
```

However when I updated the README.md and pushed the changes to git. I can only see

```
<dependency><groupId>com.company.dept.project.team</groupId>   <artifactId>LibraryName</artifactId><version>1.0</version></dependency>
```

Can someone help in displaying the actual coordinates in different lines as shown below?

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.company.dept.project.team</groupId>
   <artifactId>LibraryName</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about a `README.md` for a GitHub project. Simply using two spaces at the end of a line inserts a line break, but still does not display the code as code. To accomplish this use a code block with syntax highlighting as described in the [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/):

````
```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.company.dept.project.team</groupId>
   <artifactId>LibraryName</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```
````

This will result in

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.company.dept.project.team</groupId>
   <artifactId>LibraryName</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```